# Use a Radiolist with Scriptreplay

Tags: scripts, dialog

I want to crate a programm using dialog that gives me a radiolist of logfiles (working) and automatically replays them using scriptreplay but I can't get it to work because the filepath that gets placed in the Temp file includes these "" things thats why scriptreplay cant find the file and won't play it. I also need the programm to automatically select the right .log file (they have the same name or I place them in the same directory) that is used in the .timing file.

```bsh
#! /bin/bash
#clear
_temp="/tmp/answer.$$"
STRING=""
COUNTER=0
for i in $(ls /mnt/home/$USER/shell_logs/*.log ); do
    let COUNTER=COUNTER+1
   STRING=$(echo $STRING \"$i\" \"$COUNTER\" \"OFF\" )
done
dialog --backtitle "Radiolist" --radiolist "test" 0 0 0 $STRING 2>$_temp
result=`cat $_temp`
clear
echo  $result
```

Comment: If you were being guided by [this response](http://askubuntu.com/a/438491/147044) at your previous question, you wouldn't have this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash
#clear
_temp="/tmp/answer.$$"
STRING=""
COUNTER=0
for i in $(ls /mnt/home/$USER/shell_logs/*.log ); do
    let COUNTER=COUNTER+1
   STRING=$(echo $STRING $i \"$COUNTER\" \"OFF\" )
done
dialog --backtitle "Radiolist" --radiolist "test" 0 0 0 $STRING 2>$_temp
result=`cat $_temp`
clear
cat $result
```